# Deep joins Cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm having troubles width the `find()` method and deep joins in cakephp 2.

I'm building a `search()` function which should search in 3 models : Contact, Building and City, where Contact contain Building which contain City.

Here's my request :

```
$options['contain'] = array(
                'User' => array(
                    'fields' => array('id', 'first_name', 'last_name')
                ),
                'Building' => array(
                    'City' => array(
                        'fields' => array('name')
                    ),
                    'fields' => array('id', 'title')
                )
        );

        $options['conditions']['OR'] = array(
            array('Contact.id LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%'),
            array('User.first_name LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%'),
            array('User.last_name LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%'),
            array('Building.title LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%'),
            array('Building.City.name LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%'),
        );

        $contacts = $this->Contact->find('all', $options);
```

But this produces the following `WHERE` condition :

```
WHERE `Contact`.`white_label_id` = 18 AND ((`User`.`first_name` LIKE '%jean%') OR (`User`.`last_name` LIKE '%jean%') OR (`Building`.`title` LIKE '%jean%') OR (`Building`.`City`.`name` LIKE '%jean%'))
```

The problem is on the City model, where I can't search in name field. Can someone help me ?

Comment: Correct me if I wrong, is that `array('Building.City.name LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%'),` or `array('City.name LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%'),`?

Comment: @KevinKyaw This not worked... In both cases I get the same message "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column City.name / Building.City.name"

Comment: Look like u need join with City Model

Comment: you think BindModel would be appropriate ?

Comment: This depend on your logic. If you don't want, you can easily join it.

Comment: I did not get more results with same request and binding : $this->Contact->bindModel(array(
    'hasOne' => array(
     'City' => array(
      'foreignKey' => false,
      'conditions' => array('City.id = Contact.Building.city_id')
     )
    )
   ));

Comment: Can you provide detail query ? I can't see the whole things.

Comment: @KevinKyaw see below message

Answer (score 0):

I get the same result "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column City.name in where clause" with bind Model :

```
$this->Contact->bindModel(array(
            'hasOne' => array(
                'City' => array(
                    'foreignKey' => false,
                    'conditions' => array('City.id = Contact.Building.city_id')
                )
            )
        ));

        $options['contain'] = array(
            'User' => array(
                'fields' => array('id', 'first_name', 'last_name'),
            ),
            'Building' => array(
                'City' => array(
                    'fields' => array('name'),
                ),
                'fields' => array('id', 'title')
            )
        );

        $options['conditions']['OR'] = array(
            array('Contact.id LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%'),
            array('User.first_name LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%'),
            array('User.last_name LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%'),
            array('Building.title LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%'),
            array('City.name LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%')
        );

        $contacts = $this->Contact->find('all', $options);
```

My WHERE clause in sql query :

```
WHERE `Contact`.`white_label_id` = 33 AND ((`Contact`.`id` LIKE '%fouillard%') OR (`User`.`first_name` LIKE '%fouillard%') OR (`User`.`last_name` LIKE '%fouillard%') OR (`Building`.`title` LIKE '%fouillard%') OR (`City`.`name` LIKE '%fouillard%'))
```

Did I mess with bindModel ?

Answer (score 0):

For `bindModel` should be like this.

```
$this->Contact->bindModel(
      array('hasOne' => array('City' => array('className' => 'Contact'))));
```

Can that be join something like this?

```
 'joins' => [
      [
          'table' => 'city',
          'alias' => 'City',
          'type' => 'INNER',
          'conditions' => [
             'Contact.city_id = City.id'
           ]
      ]
  ],
```

Comment: I still get the same result with this form of bindModel. Is this wrong ? $options['conditions']['OR'] = array(
    array('Contact.id LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%'),
    array('User.first_name LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%'),
    array('User.last_name LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%'),
    array('Building.title LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%'),
    array('City.name LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%')
   );

Comment: Is there any hasone or hasMany in your Contract and City model ?

Comment: yes, Contact have another hasOne and 0 hasMany. City has 2 hasMany. Does that impact on the bindModel ?

Comment: Can you join instead of bindModel ? If can, pls check again.

Comment: Yes I can, but will I be able to search on City.name if I join (I already have conditions on User, Contact and Building models) ?

Answer (score 0):

i come back to you because i finally found the solution which was a join for each model used in the search function :

```
            $options['contain'] = array(
            'User' => array(
                'fields' => array('id', 'first_name', 'last_name'),
            ),
            'Manager' => array(
                'fields' => array('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone'),
            ),
            'Building' => array(
                'City' => array(
                    'fields' => array('name', 'id'),
                ),
                'fields' => array('id', 'title')
            ),
            'Step',
        );

        $options['joins'] = array(
            array(
                'table' => 'cities',
                'alias' => 'City',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => [
                    'Building.city_id = City.id'
                ]
            ),
        );

        $options['conditions']['OR'] = array(
            array('Contact.id LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%'),
            array('User.first_name LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%'),
            array('User.last_name LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%'),
            array('Building.title LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%'),
            array('City.name LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%')
        );

        $contacts = $this->Contact->find('all', $options);
```

Tanks to all who helped me. I hope this will help someone.